# why markup languages like facebook FBML or google g exists?

Tags: xml, fbml, google-plus-one, xfbml

I thought long and hard and can't think of problems that cannot be solved by html, css, javascript and iframes.

Can somebody shed some light on reasoning's behind FBML and google g markup languages existance. How and what do they make easier?

**g: plusone example (code used when adding like button for example):**

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>
```

**or facebook fbml example - ( code used when adding facebook like button for example):**

```
<fb:like send="false" layout="box_count" width="450" show_faces="true" action="recommend" font="verdana"></fb:like>

<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Looking on example above - can't we simply replace

```
<g and <fb
```

elements with divs that have **facebook** or **plusone** class for example?

P.S. not sure if g is a language - at least I couln't find anything about it while googling. Really sucks when they use these single character names like g or c.

Comment: `g` and `fb` are called XML namespaces. Namespaces and class names are not quite the same thing.

Comment: I thought so. it's just that facebook called it "Facebook Markup Language" for some reason.

Comment: Actually, yes, FBML is a markup language in its own right. It defines its own set of elements. So when you use it in an XHTML document you need to use the `fb` namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably to avoid namespacing issues.

If you implement this with a DIV you have to make 100% sure that the classname you choose is unique, so that it doesn't conflict with the user's classes. For example `<div class="google-plusone"` would not be a good name because what if the user wrapped this code into his own container and named it "google-plusone" too (not unlikely)?

So Google would have to come up with ugly class names like "google----plusone", etc. It's much more elegant to specify a new XML namespace and put their code inside.